# Fetching wrong date from MongoDB in java

Tags: java, mongodb

In mongo db Date is present in  "createdDate": ISODate("2023-07-01T02:02:06.261+05:30")
while am fetching in java language it's giving this date which is wrong "Fri Jun 30 20:32:06 UTC 2023". while am changing date to "createdDate": ISODate("2023-07-01T07:02:06.261+05:30") it's giving correct date Sat Jul 01 01:32:06 UTC 2023

Am expecting if date is present in MongoDB in this format "createdDate": ISODate("2023-07-01T02:02:06.261+05:30") while fetching in java it should give correct date i.e Sat Jul 01 01:32:06 UTC 2023

Comment: Its pain to read this. Can you please format your question so we can have easier task to at least spot the differences between dates ?

Comment: And why this `2023-07-01T02:02:06.261+05:30` should be equal to `Sat Jul 01 01:32:06 UTC 2023`? Those are 2 different points in time. On the contrary, `2023-07-01T02:02:06.261+05:30` and `Fri Jun 30 20:32:06 UTC 2023` looks like the same point in time which is more than expected

Comment: It is giving the correct date, subtract 5hs 30 mints from your time, it matches the GMT/UTC time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sat Jul 01 01:32:06 UTC 2023 is 5 hours ahead of ISODate("2023-07-01T02:02:06.261+05:30"), so would not be correct.

Comment: @Antoniossss
I have date value in mongoDB i.e ISODate("2023-07-01T02:02:06.261+05:30")
while am reading this date from Java by connecting to MongoDB it's giving me
This Date Fri Jun 30 20:32:06 UTC 2023.

Actually Jun 30 is not present in MongoDB why it should give that date instead of 01 July

Note* forget about time in this case

Comment: @Community
In MongoDB date value is ISODate("2023-07-01T02:02:06.261+05:30")

In java, at the time of reading this date it's giving  Fri Jun 30 20:32:06 UTC 2023.

So, My doubt is why 30 jun why not 01 july.

Comment: @BhaskarWhitebox and that is PERFECTLY FINE.

Comment: @Antoniossss i need to show that date which is present in MongDB to end user in UI side, if am showing the wrong date then it's not good right.

Comment: Format it to the required timezone on the frontend app

Comment: Giving correct output after doing required time format.